# Unable to figure out why my solution for Codechef problem MXEVNSUB is failing

Tags: c++

Question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/MXEVNSUB

The following is my understanding of the problem.

This problem is asking for the maximum length of its contiguous subsequence with an even sum.

For

N = 1, Sum = 1 (odd sum but we need not bother about N = 1, since 2 <= N <= 10000)

N = 2, Sum = 3 (odd sum)

N = 3, Sum = 6 (even sum)

N = 4, Sum = 10 (even sum)

N = 5, Sum = 15 (odd sum)

N = 6, Sum = 21 (odd sum)

.
.
.

N = k- 1, Sum = ((k - 1) * k) / 2 (I assume it’s sum is odd)

N = k, Sum = (k * (k + 1)) / 2 (Worst case, this one might be odd too)

So I used the following logic in my code.

If the sum of numbers up to N is even, I can simply print the value of N and break out of the loop, else I reduce N by 1 and repeat the process.

The inner while loop in my code is a O(1) operation since in the worst case it runs 3 times (2 times for odd sum and the third time when sum is even)

Here is the code which is giving me WA

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int tc; cin >> tc;
    while(tc--){
        int n; cin >> n;
        if(n == 2) {
            cout<<-1<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        while(n){
            if( ( (n * (n + 1) ) / 2 ) % 2 == 0){
                cout << n << endl;
                break;
            }
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to submit the solution and it works for the sample test cases but is giving me Wrong Answer on submitting.

Comment: Solving Competitive programming problems or coding puzzles as you like to call them requires use of logic building and raw ability to make observations using the given information. Data structures and the right algorithms are mere tools. And sorry to burst your bubble, but there are a bunch of resources (not just books) to learn C++ tutorials or where certain underlying algorithms ("tricks") are used in competitive programming problems. Your comment clearly shows your half understanding about competitive programming problems.

Comment: I asked the above question because I was stuck on the problem due to some reason unknown to me but definitely not cause I missed some trick or some maths. Thanks for the quick judgement and downvote!

Comment: Note that the subsequence may begin at 2. In practice, the result is always n or n-1.

Comment: These challenge/competitive coding web sites are mostly for highly skilled, experienced C++ hackers to spend some free time solving useless coding puzzles. Trying to learn C++ from them is like trying to learn ice-skating by playing a hockey game against a team consisting of Wayne Gretzky, Mario Lemiuex, Sidney Crosby, Mark Messier, Brian Leetch, and Phil Esposito. It's going to be far more productive to learn C++, first, using any number of reputable, edited, textbooks; and then try your luck at competitive coding or challenge/competition sites.

Comment: And, yes, I know very little of "competitive coding". But I do know enough to know that anyone at a job interview and writes `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` will not get the job because they lack core understanding of the C++ library. All they know is how to solve useless coding puzzles. A key part of it is knowing C++ is knowing where each class or template is defined and used.  That's not a trivial data point; unfortunately "competitive coding" sites only encourage bad programming practices, like non-standard header files and compiler-specific language features, instead of proper C++ knowledge.